# How to add a statement that checks for numbers or punctuation in a string

Tags: list, python-3.x, if-statement

I currently have a code that translates english into morse code. It works fine but I want to add another argument that allows the program to print `###` whenver a number or punctuation is inputted.

```
translation_table = [["a",".-"],["b","-..."],["c","-.-."],["d","-.."],
["e","."],["f","..-."],["g","--."],["h","...."],
["i",".."],["j",".---"],["k","-.-"],["l",".-.."],
["m","--"],["n","-."],["o","---"],["p",".--."],
["q","--.-"],["r",".-."],["s","..."],["t","-"],
["u","..-"],["v","...-"],["w",".--"],["x","-..-"],
["y","-.--"],["z","--.."]]

word_index = 0
english = input("Enter a sentence to be translated(*** to end): ")
words = list(english)
translated_sentence = ""
while word_index < len(words):
    if english == "***":
        print("Program has ended")
        break
    translation_index = 0
    while translation_index < len(translation_table):
        if translation_table[translation_index][0] == words[word_index]:
           translated_sentence = translated_sentence + translation_table[translation_index][1]
           translation_index = 27
        elif words[word_index] == " ":
            translated_sentence = translated_sentence + "   "
            translation_index = 27
        else :
            translation_index = translation_index + 1
```

I was thinking of adding another elif line that was something like

```
elif words[word_index][0] == : 
        translated_sentence = translated_sentence + "###"
            translation_index = 27
```

but I have no idea how to make it check for only numbers and punctuation in the string. For example, `hi!` would print `.....###`. 
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simplified version. I turned your translation_table `list` into a `dict`. I am also using the [isalpha()](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha) method to check if a given character is a letter.

```
translationDict = {'a':'.-', 'b':'-...', 'c':'-.-.', 'd':'-..', 'e':'.', 
                   'f':'..-.', 'g':'--.', 'h':'....', 'i':'..', 'j':'.---', 
                   'k':'-.-', 'l':'.-..', 'm':'--', 'n':'-.', 'o':'---', 
                   'p':'.--.', 'q':'--.-', 'r':'.-.', 's':'...', 't':'-', 
                   'u':'..-', 'v':'...-', 'w':'.--', 'x':'-..-', 'y':'-.--',
                   'z':'--..'}

english = input('Enter a sentence to be translated: ')  

for character in english:
    if character is ' ':
        print(' ', end='')
    elif character.isalpha():
        print(translationDict[character], end='')
    else:
        print('###', end='')
```

Here is similar implementation using a list:

```
translation_table = [["a",".-"],["b","-..."],["c","-.-."],["d","-.."],
                    ["e","."],["f","..-."],["g","--."],["h","...."],
                    ["i",".."],["j",".---"],["k","-.-"],["l",".-.."],
                    ["m","--"],["n","-."],["o","---"],["p",".--."],
                    ["q","--.-"],["r",".-."],["s","..."],["t","-"],
                    ["u","..-"],["v","...-"],["w",".--"],["x","-..-"],
                    ["y","-.--"],["z","--.."]]

english = input('Enter a sentence to be translated: ')  

for character in english:
    if character is ' ':
        print(' ', end='')
    elif character.isalpha():
        for i in translation_table:
            if character in i:
                print(i[1], end ='')
    else:
        print('###', end='')
```

Comment: I should of put in my original question that we weren't allowed to use dictionary, oops! Yea that would probably be the best way of doing things.

Comment: I have added a list example to my answer.